# Remove hash from Link-component using react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm setting up a download-button on my webpage, and am meeting some issues using HashRouter. Since HashRouter will add a hash in the URL, it changes the path for the file. It works with BrowserRouter, but in HashRouter the hash makes the link invalid.

Is there any way to remove the hash in this instance? Or is there another way to solve this?

```
<Link to="..\files\Product\demo\win\Product_setup.zip" target="_blank" download>
     <button class="button-demo">Windows version</button>
</Link>
```